# Jquery Steps ->button click->go to step

Tags: jquery, wizard, jquery-steps

I'm using the [jquery steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) wizard in asp.net application.
I have problem with event to change step when click the button.
Initailize steps in file.js

```
var WizardFunc = function () {
    var wizard = null;
    return {
        WizardSet: function () {
            wizard = $('#order').steps({
                bodyTag: "fieldset",
                transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
                headerTag: "h1",
                autoFocus: true
            });
        },
        WizardStepAdd: function (index, title, contentId) {
            wizard.steps("insert", index, {
                title: title,
                content: "<div id='" + contentId + "'></div>"
            });
        },
        WizardGoToStep: function (index) {
            wizard.steps("setStep", 1);
        },
        WizardStepRemove: function (index) {
            wizard.remove(index);
        }
    }
}();
```

I try call to function:

```
$("#new-size-container").on("click", ".add-size", function () { 
WizardFunc.WizardGoToStep(1);}
```

return error:

```
Not yet implemented!
```

Q: How call function to change step index when button click ?

Comment: Please show how you've initialized Steps.

Comment: Hi, I edit my post and include how init Steps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this plugin does not support the features you are currently using. Here is the code from plugin

```
/**
 * Sets a specific step object by index.
 *
 * @method setStep
 * @param index {Integer} An integer that belongs to the position of a step
 * @param step {Object} The step object to change
 **/
$.fn.steps.setStep = function (index, step)
{
    throw new Error("Not yet implemented!");
};

/**
 * Skips an certain amount of steps.
 *
 * @method skip
 * @param count {Integer} The amount of steps that should be skipped
 * @return {Boolean} Indicates whether the action executed
 **/
$.fn.steps.skip = function (count)
{
    throw new Error("Not yet implemented!");
};
```

Comment: Hi dilish, I see setStep function, but have U got example how use setStep ?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, setStep function is not supported by the plugin.

Comment: @JakubKlekota I don't know if you or anyone else coming to this question has the same problem but I just faked it by called `steps("previous")` x number of time to go back to the start depending on the number of steps in my wizard. Silly I know, but it worked. Implementing a `setStep` should be relatively straightforward though.

Answer (score 5):

For any person who are coming to this old unresolved post, please note that this plugin is able to navigate dynamically to step (next or previous) as described here : http://www.rafaelstaib.com/category/jQuery-Steps

```
 $(this).steps("previous");
```

or

```
 $(this).steps("next");
```

Comment: Cheers, I solved the same problem by just calling `previous` in a loop depending on what index I was on and what index I wanted to navigate to.